# How to check if 24 hours have passed in Swift

Tags: swift3, nsdate

I have to implement in my app where after a user had saved his recording, I will have to determine if 24 hours have passed from the creation date of that recording. So far what I have at the moment is just to determine if current date is not equal to the creation date. I really appreciate anybody's help, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can use `UserDefault` to save the date upon creation of the record. The syntax will be

```
UserDefaults.standard.set(Date(), forKey:"creationTime")
```

Whenever you want to check the saved date, retrieve it in this way

```
if let date = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "creationTime") as? Date {
    if let diff = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.hour], from: date, to: Date()).hour, diff > 24 {
        //do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but that is not the answer that I was looking for, I already have data stored in coredata. I already have everything set up. All I really need is to calculate or compare if 24 hours have passed since creation date.

Comment: @TomDerryMarionMantilla Oh, look at the updated code

Comment: Oh ok, thank you so much, is it ok if I will test this first before I vote your answer?

Comment: @TomDerryMarionMantilla Of course! Let me know if you have problems & concerns

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: Sir one question, is this still applicable even if the user fails to open the app within 24 hours? Let's say the user opened it after 2 days, will it still apply that 24 hours have already passed from the creation date? Will it mean 24 hours + have already passed since the creation date?

Comment: @TomDerryMarionMantilla The method calculate the diff between two dates. You said that you saved a date to core data when something happened. So after that, when you call this method to check, it calculates hours different between the saved date and the current date. In your case if the user opens the app after two days, the calculation result will be 48 hours and you can then perform some action.

Comment: I tried 1 hour and it worked, so I guess so does will 24 hours. I accepted your answer. Thank you sir :)

Comment: @TomDerryMarionMantilla Don't forget to mark it as correct answer. Thanks

Comment: Should be `diff > 23` or `diff >= 24` to determine if 24 hours have passed

Answer (score 17):

You can easily check if the time interval since date is greater or equal to a TTL of 24 hours.

```
let start = Date()
let timeToLive: TimeInterval = 60 * 60 * 24 // 60 seconds * 60 minutes * 24 hours

let isExpired = Date().timeIntervalSince(start) >= timeToLive
```