# SWIFT Expiring a singleton instance after 24 Hours

Tags: swift

I have a singleton in my app which holds user tokens for API access. These tokens expire server side every 24 hours. I need my app to do the same. I'm storing the value within UserDefaults. I know that's not secure :).

I have a class function for the singleton which destroy()s it when called. I need to make sure this class func is called every 24 hours after the singleton has been initialized.

I did a bunch of searching, and I literally can't find anything about expiring objects in Swift. Maybe I'm using the wrong key terms? Here is my code:

```
class AimsiAdminController {

    private static var privateShared:AimsiAdminController?

    class func shared() -> AimsiAdminController {
        guard let unwrappedShared = privateShared else {
            privateShared = AimsiAdminController()
            return privateShared!
        }
        return unwrappedShared
    }

    class func destroy() {
        privateShared = nil
    }

    let securityToken: String
    private let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


    private init() {
        self.securityToken = self.defaults.string(forKey: "securityToken") ?? ""
    }
}
```

Comment: "I need to make sure this class func is called every 24 hours after the singleton has been initialized." Unclear why this is hard. Record the time of initialization and start watching the clock (a repeating Timer with an interval of one minute will do). If 24 hours or more has elapsed, bingo.

Comment: You can check there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046891/how-to-check-if-24-hours-have-passed-in-swift

Comment: temporary token should be given by server, user can simply manually change date and time on device

Comment: You don't need a singleton just to read user defaults.

Comment: Unrelated but what is that *objective-c-ish* `privateShared` property for? Please, this is Swift. Use a constant: `static let shared = AimsiAdminController()` and delete the entire `shared()` method. `Static` constants are initialized lazily be default.

Comment: you have conflicting conditions: do you want it to expire "every 24 hours" based on some server expiration timestamp, or "24 hours after the singleton has been initialized". For instance app could be restarted 1 hour before token expiration.

Comment: you are right @KirilS. It needs to expire 24 hours after the token was fetched via my api. I'm assuming this means I just need to store that timestamp in user defaults as well, and do a check every time it is initialized?

Comment: you definitely need to check it when app is initialized, but also you need to make sure that you renew it if it expires while the app is running. So you could either schedule as Mojtaba suggested (just not after 24 hours, but rather few min before token expiration), or you could create an internal notification to the app scheduled to that time

Comment: Above and beyond the rationale provided by @vadian, you should note that your singleton pattern is not thread-safe. Simple `static let` is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

This way:

```
private init() {
    self.securityToken = self.defaults.string(forKey: "securityToken") ?? ""
    let interval = DispatchTime.now() + 24 * 60 * 60
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: interval) { AimsiAdminController.destroy() }
}
```

Each time you initialize, it will call destroy after the given time

Comment: But not recommended.

Comment: Why wouldn't you recommend it?

Comment: Because of the heart of the Singleton definition. I prefer to use `property wrapper` in upcoming swift for this type of need.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, but the link that @Vicaren provided in the comments above is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The link that @Vicaren provided in the comments above is exactly what I needed. Hopefully the terms I used in this question will help lead someone else to that answer, as I was not able to find it searching myself.